# Running Python script from PHP controller

Tags: php, python, mysql, symfony

I have a python script which can preprocesses an image(increase contrast).

It works fine through the command line.

I want to call that script from PHP web application. And I want to use an image stored in MySQL database.

Here is the python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2
import numpy as np
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.switch_backend('Qt4Agg') 

img = cv2.imread('original.png')

bilateral = cv2.bilateralFilter(img,9,75,75)

img = cv2.imread('bilaterla_filtered.png')

# generating the kernels

kernel_sharpen_3 = np.array([[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],
                             [-1,2,2,2,-1],
                             [-1,2,8,2,-1],
                             [-1,2,2,2,-1],
                             [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]]) / 8.0

output_3 = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel_sharpen_3)

cv2.imwrite('edge_enhancement.png',output_3)

img = cv2.imread('edge_enhancement.png')

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

hist,bins = np.histogram(gray_image.flatten(),256,[0,256])
cdf = hist.cumsum()

cdf_m = np.ma.masked_equal(cdf,0)
cdf_m = (cdf_m - cdf_m.min())*255/(cdf_m.max()-cdf_m.min())
cdf = np.ma.filled(cdf_m,0).astype('uint8')

img2 = cdf[img]
image_enhanced=img2
cv2.imwrite('Final.png',image_enhanced)
```

What should I do in the controller

1. How do I send the image from mysql database as a parameter to the
   script?
2. How do I execute the script and store the resulting image in the
   database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters You should redo your python script to make it parameterized. 
Something like this:

```
img = cv2.imread('original.png')
```

should not exist in your script! You should receive filepath as a script's paramter.

The rest pretty much depends on how You implemented it and how do You want it to work.

If You want to execute programs from within php script please take a look at [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)